# How to use Socket.IO in TypeScript with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: socket.io, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am looking for a simple example of how to get Socket.IO working with TypeScript while using Visual Studio Code. I am running on Node.js.

I have installed the d.ts for socket.io, and it appears in the typings folder.

```
cd src/
tsd query socket.io --action install
```

I have added socket.io to the package.json dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
    "socket.io" : "*"
}
```

The run `npm install`, and the package files are showing in the `node_modules` directory.

I then try to import socket.io in TypeScript, and here is where I don't know what I am doing. I tried this:

```
import * as sio from 'socket.io';
```

It doesn't complain about anything, but when I just to use `sio` it does not give me any IntelliSense. So I feel like I have done something wrong.

Is that the correct `import`? Are there any **up to date** examples around?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> `import * as sio from 'socket.io';`

That is the right import. You can see it in use here : https://github.com/TypeScriptBuilder/tsb/blob/ac87f359201a25e1bbb44f72093487348f3d28d3/src/socketLib/socketLibServer.ts#L2 Try restarting VS code.

> Are there any up to date examples around?

I use socket.io quite heavily here : https://github.com/TypeScriptBuilder/tsb